# How to use the Starteam vcmutility to automate a selective rebase?

Tags: version-control, rebase, starteam

In Borland Starteam I would like to automate a very simple rebase that only repins files (i.e. ignores everything else - assuming to be done with the wizard).

Looking at the StarTeam Help "VCMUtility Session Options" I would like to set my DefaultAction for everything to ignore -- except source.modified should be repin.  I do not see an obvious way to override all  (since this is a union of  listing all combinations is not an option).

Does anyone have any example config files?  Or experience with doing this with StarTeam?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the repin term, what does that mean?

Comment: In Starteam a file can be shared (linked) from a different branch or even project.  If the original file changes, so does the location it is shared into.  Alternatively, you can share a file into your view and then "pin" or freeze to a version or time of the original.  It all gets complicated quickly and I'm not advocating using Starteam in general, but it's what we use ;-)